# make class such that configure one time & use method of that class in any file in project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, use-strict

All i want is to make 1 time configuration in main file(main.js) while server starts... And use method of that class multiple time in different files(conn1.js,conn2.js)...

i am making a npm module which is not working while using 'use strict'. but if i use global variable while removing 'use strict' it's working fine..

i have defined a class like this..

index.js

```
'use strict';

var  pg = require('pg'),_ = require('lodash');

function PgAdaptor(options) {
    options = options || {};

    options.user = options.user ;

    options.password = options.password ;

    options.host = options.host || "localhost";

    options.port = options.port || 5432;

    options.database = options.database || 'postgres';

    this.connectionString = "postgres://"+options.user+":"+options.password+"@"+options.host+":"+options.port+"/"+options.database;

    this.options = options;
    this.getConnection = function (callback) {
        console.log("Establishing connection with postgre");
        pg.connect(this.connectionString, callback);
    }
}
_.extend(PgAdaptor.prototype, {

getCon : function(callback){

        this.getConnection(function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error in connection : " + error);
                callback(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Got connection for executing query");
                callback(null, result);
            }
        });
    } 
})

function pgadaptor (options) {
    return new PgAdaptor(options);
}

module.exports = pgadaptor;
```

now i am using the above class in my main file like this...

main.js

```
'use strict';
pgadaptor = require('pgadaptor')({
    user : "postgres",
    password : "passpass",
    database : "test"
});
```

i want to configure this main file only once . and i want to use the **getCon** method in many files.

conn1.js

```
'use strict';
require('pgadaptor').getCon(function(err,res){
    if(err){
        console.log("ERROR!!")
    }
    console.log("SUCCESS!!")
})
```

conn2.js

```
'use strict';    
require('pgadaptor').getCon(function(err,res){
    if(err){
        console.log("ERROR!!")
    }
        console.log("SUCCESS!!")
})
```

Is this right approach to make  class structure in npm modules ??